# Entity Framework, how and where to call stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework to create a Web API.

I have a stored procedure that receives some parameters and then creates a new record in two different tables.

Since every table has its own controller, where should I put the call to the stored procedure? And how should I call it?

Comment: You can access the database context directly - it has some methods for executing stuff

Comment: _"where should I put the call to the stored procedure?"_ - wherever it makes sense...

Comment: `Since every table has its own controller` - Here do you use Poco class models to insert data into tables or here also you are using stored procedures only?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like currently you are adopting a REST-style Web API. Each table has it's own HTTP endpoint and you manipulate records more or less directly with GET/PUT/POST/DELETE. However, your new action is a more complex operation. It may be deemed something more like an RPC-style call. You might want to create a new controller for RPC-style endpoints (routes) for your client to call. In the end it's all up to your creativity.

In my experience even the most strict adherence to REST-style convention often needs at least some RPC endpoints for more complex operations. Sometimes I include them in the other controllers and sometimes they live on their own.